# Erlang: How does one avoid Lists being translated to ASCII Strings?

Tags: list, erlang, ascii

[97, 98, 99]. yields "abc", in the Erlang shell. I realize this is because the ASCII values of a, b and c are 97, 98 and 99 respectively.

So.. how would one go about returning [97,98,99] without Erlang translating it to ASCII?

Comment: Just a note: It is important to realize that "abc" and [97,98,99] is _exactly_ the same thing. You are just interpreting the same data in two different ways and one way the Erlang shell interprets this data is as an ASCII string. I understand what you mean though, just wanted it to be clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `io:format("~w~n", [ListHere])`, which should simply avoid interpreting the data.

Comment: io:format("~w~n", [97,98,99]) is bringing up errors for me. Is that how you meant it?

Comment: `List = [97,98,99], io:format("~w~n", [List]).` which means `io:format("~w~n", [[97,98,99]]).`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

> YourList ++ [0]

With "abc"

> "abc" ++ [0]
>
> [97,98,99,0]

Comment: This is not a very good idea :) Manipulating your data just to not getting it translated? :) Don't do this... Sorry have a down vote good sir.

Comment: @Mazen - We are are only talking about the Shell (REPL).  If someone wants to append a [0] to an expression they are evaluating in the shell, I say no foul. Just don't copy this expression into your source code like that.