# Integer in list printed as "\v"?

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension

Can someone explain this unexpected list comprehension strangeness from Erlang?

```
4> [A+B || [A, B] <- [1, 2, 3, [5, 6]]].
"\v"
```

Expected: `11`

Got: `"\v"`

What must be done to get the expected output?

Comment: You can use `shell:strings(false)` but keep in mind that this option is global. [Can I disable printing lists of small integers as strings in Erlang shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348087/can-i-disable-printing-lists-of-small-integers-as-strings-in-erlang-shell)

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7371955/113848) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20792966/113848).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html):

> A string is a list of codepoints, binaries with UTF-8-encoded codepoints (UTF-8 binaries), or a mix of the two.

```
"abcd"               % is a valid string  
<<"abcd">>           % is a valid string  
["abcd"]             % is a valid string  
<<"abc..åäö"/utf8>>  % is a valid string  
<<"abc..åäö">>       % is NOT a valid string,  
                     % but a binary with Latin-1-encoded codepoints  
[<<"abc">>, "..åäö"] % is a valid string  
[atom]               % is NOT a valid string
```

So in above you got integer 11 inside a list or `[11]`:

```
Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> [A+B || [A, B] <- [1, 2, 3, [5, 6]]].
"\v"
%% With hd/1 function you can get first element (head) of a list
2> hd([A+B || [A, B] <- [1, 2, 3, [5, 6]]]).
11
3> [11].
"\v"
```

Erlang VM prints a printable list in form of string. Currently it supports two printable range. `latin1` which is default and `unicode`.

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> io:printable_range().
latin1
```

You can change `latin1` to `unicode` using [+pc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html#+pc) flag:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> [1662]. %% not printable in latin1 range
[1662]
2> 
BREAK: (a)bort (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo (l)oaded
       (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
a
$ erl +pc unicode
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> [1662].
"پ"
2>
```